# Cannot connect to smtp mail server

Tags: centos, smtp, openssl, telnet

I have an installation of Postfix & Dovecot on a Centos 7 server. While being logged into the server via ssh I am able to use telnet and openssl to connect to localhost like

```
openssl s_client -starttls smtp -crlf -connect localhost:25
```

authenticate myself, and send an email. However, when I try to connect to the server from my local Computer, replacing localhost with the server name, I get the error message

```
connect: Connection refused
connect:errno=61
```

Using telnet I get the error

```
Trying XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX...
telnet: connect to address XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX: Connection refused
telnet: Unable to connect to remote host
```

The file `/etc/postfix/master.cf`contains the lines

```
smtp      inet  n   -   n   -   -   smtpd
submission inet n   -   -   -   -   smtpd
```

The command `netstat -tpnl | grep :25` results in

```
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:25              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      10327/master        
tcp6       0      0 :::25                   :::*                    LISTEN      10327/master
```

Calling `systemctl status iptables.service` on the server yields

```
● iptables.service
Loaded: not-found (Reason: No such file or directory)
Active: inactive (dead)
```

Entering my mail server at mrtoolbox.com results in the message

```
Connecting to XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX
1/20/2016 3:43:42 PM Connection attempt #1 - Unable to connect after 15 seconds. [15.01 sec]

PWS3v2 15193ms
```

Can you give me some hints what I might have missed or how to check what is going wrong, here?

Comment: Check your firewall.

Comment: Thanks Michael, you were absolutely right! And Iain, you  probably aswell. I didn't find the other post. Is there a way to delete delete this thread?